# Order By with DAY(), MONTH() is not working in doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

I am trying to order results of my query by day and month, here is my code

```
public function getUserBirthday($idList)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder->select('fb')
            ->from('Wishwish\ApplicationBundle\Entity\FbUser', 'fb')
            ->where(' Week(fb.birthday)<=  Week(:now)+2')
            ->andWhere('Week(fb.birthday)>  Week(:now)')
            ->andWhere('fb.id IN (:idList)')
            ->orderBy('DAY(fb.birthday)')
            ->addOrderBy('MONTH(fb.birthday)');
        $queryBuilder->setParameter('now', new \DateTime());
        $queryBuilder->setParameter('idList',$idList);
        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

this id the error displayed :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 170: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
1 linked Exception: QueryException »
```

update =>solution :
the trick was to use createNativeQuery

```
public function getUserBirthday($idList)
{
   $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
            $rsm->addEntityResult('Wishwish\ApplicationBundle\Entity\FbUser', 'fb');
            $rsm->addFieldResult('fb', 'birthday', 'birthday');
            $rsm->addFieldResult('fb', 'picture', 'picture');
            $rsm->addFieldResult('fb', 'name', 'name');
            $rsm->addFieldResult('fb', 'id', 'id');

            $sql ='select *  from fb_user
            where (Week(birthday)<=  Week(:now)+2) and  (Week(birthday)>  Week(:now))
            and (id IN (:idList)) ORDER By DAY (birthday),MONTH (birthday)';
            $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
            $query->setParameter('now', new \DateTime());
            $query->setParameter('idList',$idList);
       return $query->getResult();

        }
```

Comment: Glad to see you got it working but your original queryBuilder should have worked and it would eliminate the need to drop down to sql.  Doctrine does not support DATE,WEEK,MONTH out of the box.  You need to install them.  Take a look at: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Date.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [createNativeQuery()](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#the-nativequery-class) method for more complex query:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;


$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('
    SELECT fb
    FROM WishwishApplicationBundle:FbUser fb
    WHERE Week(fb.birthday) <= Week(:now)+2
        AND Week(fb.birthday) > Week(:now)
        AND fb.id IN (:idList)
    ORDER BY DAY(fb.birthday) ASC, MONTH(fb.birthday) ASC
    ', $rsm)
    ->setParameter('now', new \DateTime())
    ->setParameter('idList',$idList);

$result = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: I just found a solution inspired from an answer to other questions:

Comment: I couln't post it because I am new here, but the trick was to use createNativeQuery() and the mapping with the fields of the database one by one

Comment: Thanks and you, it useful for me too )